# Preventing a regex from matching by using a negative look behind

Tags: regex, string, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

I've got a sample regex that I'm working with and I'm confused on why the negative lookbehind isn't preventing matches from happening.

With this expression `^((?<!foo)[a-z]+ ?)+$` I would expect the following string to not be a valid match `bar foobar baz` since there is the string `foo` and then some letters following it.

Even just `foobar` matches, which I would definitely expect not to. I know it's related to the `+` after the `[a-z]` matches.

`^((?<!foo)[a-z] ?)+$` matches on `fob`, but not on `foob` which is what I would expect to be happening.

What do I need to change to get the the `bar foobar baz` string to not match?

Comment: That's not a useful question. `^(?!)` is a regex that does not match `bar foobar baz`, but you haven't explained what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Why would you expect `foobar` to not match? It consists of a beginning of the string, which is not preceded by `foo` (the beginning of the string is not preceded by anything), followed by one or more letters.

Comment: I suppose it would but it wouldn't match anything else either, including `this is a sample string`

Comment: Shouldn't the negative lookbehind prevent it from matching? The capture group should be saying match on any string that does not start with foo.

Comment: It's look-behind, not look-ahead. It does not say "a string that does not start with foo", it says "a string that is not preceded by foo".

Comment: Hah, well, there you go! Thanks for that!

Comment: Your question does not say you want to match `this is a sample string`. All you've told us so far is that you do not want to match `bar foobar baz`, but there's no explanation why or what you do want to match..

Answer (score 1):

You already know that you have to drop that `+` from `[a-z]+` in order to get the expected results. But you may ask why? See the following behaviors.

with `[a-z]+`, that lookbehind starts to assert at the following positions:

```
 bar foobar baz
 ^   ^      ^  ^
```

but with `[a-z]` it is different:

```
 bar foobar baz
 ^^^ ^^^^^^ ^^^^
        ^
```

As you can see, in the first form, `(?<!foo)` passes because all those 4 positions aren't preceded by `foo` but in the second form it stops matching right after second `o` because there is a `foo` preceding `b`.